# tf.losses.mean_squared_error with negative target

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, reinforcement-learning, loss-function, q-learning

I'm using Q learning and i want to know if i can use the tf.losses.mean_squared_error loss calculation function if i have a reward function which can give negative rewards.

Because if i have for exemple as output of my network the following Q values : (0.1, 0.2, 1), and i calculate that my real Q values should be (0.1, -5, 1), if i use the mean_squared_error function the loss for the second Q value will go positive am i wrong ? Because of the square operation so the gradient descend will not be based on correct loss ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes It works well.

You should concern the `mse` cost function.

```
mse = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square((x*w+b)-y))
```

The cost function calculates to square of a difference. It means always `-` values becomes `+`.

And, You are correct.
`7-1` and `5+ -1` are same cost as 36.

For more understanding of Gradient descent, You need to know how to minimize `mse`. 
From the Below Image, You can see current `mse` by `x*w+b`.
At this point, Gradient descent gets a slope to decide a direction of w to be changed.

[image]

The slope is calculated by a **derivative**.

[image]

You can see the below formula after derivative of the `mse` function.

[image]

So, You can see the direction of W that The W will be moved to the left if `((w*x-y)*x) > 0` and will be moved to the right if not.

Comment: Ok i see ! Thank you for the time spent making that good answer !

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use safely the Mean Squared Error (MSE) loss function even if the reward function can give negative values.

As you have commented, the MSE function will be positive always due to the square operation. However, this is a desirable effect.

Think, for example, in a simple linear regression. All the loss function values are positive, independently if the error is positive or negative. This give place to a convex loss function with a global minimum, where gradient descent works perfectly.

The following schema (from [Gradient Descent: All You Need to Know](https://hackernoon.com/gradient-descent-aynk-7cbe95a778da) article) illustrates the gradient descent process, which may helps to a better understanding of what I mean:

[image]

Comment: Thank for your answer ! but one thing i still don't understand, so if the MSE loss calculation is effectively going positive even if the difference between real and target is negative, assuming i have real Q value = 1 and a target Q equal to -5, how is the gradient descend correctly minimize the loss in the good direction ? because the square difference between 1 and -5 is the same than between 1 and 7 isn't it ? maybe i misunderstand something ?

Comment: Welcome, it seems now everything is clear, so I'm not going to update the answer.